# Triggering Vuex Store State Change via Mapped Actions in Vue Render Function

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, modal-dialog, vuex, nuxt.js

Ive got a render function for a slider that opens up a modal when an image is clicked. I have the modal state in my Vuex store and need to dispatch an action from the image tag in my render function.

I have a click event attached to it just like in the official vue documentation, and the vuex store state mapped to my components scope but I'm having issues incorporating mapped actions in my render function.

The goal is to change the state from false to true so the modal opens.

I'm relatively new to working with vue in-depth so I'm not sure how to go about this. All my previous attempts have failed and I could really use some guidance in this area. I'm sure it's a really simple solution, I just haven't been able to find it

I have two approaches to accessing the Vuex store. I'm fine with whatever works best.

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['modalState']),
  modalState() {
    return this.$store.state.toggleSwitches.modal_on
  }
},
```

I set up the mapped actions in my component methods

```
methods: {
  ...mapMutations(['TOGGLE_MODAL']),
  ...mapActions({ modalSwitch: 'modalSwitch' })
  modalClick() {
    this.$store.dispatch('modalSwitch') // commits TOGGLE_MODAL
  }
},
```

And here is my render function that's supposed to handle the click event.

```
h(
  'slide',
     {
       attrs: {
         class: 'particle-inner project_slide flex'
       },
       props: {
         index: ucid++
       }
     },
     [
       h('img', {
         attrs: {
           src: imageContent[i], 
           class: 'packet-inner project_content'
         },
         on: {
           click(e, modalClick) {
             EventBus.$emit('clicked_image', imageContent[i]) 
             EventBus.$emit('image_group', imageLogGroup)
             EventBus.$emit(
               'image_index',
               indexOf(imageLogGroup, imageContent[i])
             )
             // return modalClick
             // EventBus.$emit('open_modal', this.modalState)
             // this.modalSwitch(TOGGLE_MODAL)
           }
         }
       })
     ]
   )
 )
```

The commented sections at the bottom of the render function are my various failed attempts to trigger a state change in the vuex store from the render function

Currently all my approaches either don't work or throw errors when I reference 'this' from the render function. I'm just looking for a good way to access and alter the Vuex store state from my render functions on click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way of getting this to work after a couple of hours of fiddling. It basically boils down to accessing the store via:

```
this.$store.state.toggleSwitches.modal_on
```

rather than via mapped getters and actions in the slider component. I then pushed that up to the Event bus and accessed the state in the modal component which does have Vuex getters mapped to its scope. From the event bus in the modal component I dispatched the modalSwitch (toggle) action to the vuex store via:

```
this.$store.dispatch('modalSwitch')
```

Here is the updated code for anyone that comes across this issue:

```
-   computed: {
-     ...mapGetters(['modalState']),
-     modalState() {
-       return this.$store.state.toggleSwitches.modal_on
-     }
-   },
-   methods: {
-     ...mapMutations(['TOGGLE_MODAL']),
-     ...mapActions({ modalSwitch: 'modalSwitch' })
-     modalClick() {
-       this.$store.dispatch('modalSwitch') // commits TOGGLE_MODAL
-     }
-   },
    h(
    'slide',
         {
           attrs: {
             class: 'particle-inner project_slide flex'
           },
           props: {
             index: ucid++
           }
         },
         [
           h('img', {
             attrs: {
               src: imageContent[i], 
               class: 'packet-inner project_content'
             },
             on: {
               click(e, modalClick) {
                 EventBus.$emit('clicked_image', imageContent[i]) 
                 EventBus.$emit('image_group', imageLogGroup)
                 EventBus.$emit(
                   'image_index',
                   indexOf(imageLogGroup, imageContent[i])
                 )
+                EventBus.$emit('open_modal', localModalState)
-                // return modalClick
-                // EventBus.$emit('open_modal', this.modalState)
-                // this.modalSwitch(TOGGLE_MODAL)
               }
             }
           })
         ]
       )
     )
```

And in the modal component:

```
created() {
    EventBus.$on('clicked_image', imageSrc => {
      this.modalImage = imageSrc
      return this.modalImage
    })
    EventBus.$on('image_group', imageGroup => {
      this.modalImageGroup = imageGroup
      return this.modalImageGroup
    })
    EventBus.$on('image_index', imageIndex => {
      this.modalIndex = imageIndex
      return this.imageIndex
    })
+   EventBus.$on('open_modal', modalState => {
+      return this.$store.dispatch('modalSwitch')
+      // changes vuex store state
+    })
```

Hope this clarifies things for anyone encountering the same issue.